# Did Saul have a legal right to give David's wife away (1 Sam. 25:44)?

Tags: 1-samuel

From the First Book of Samuel, we are told:

> **1 Samuel 25:44**: "Now *Saul had given Michal his daughter, David’s wife*, to Palti the son of Laish, who was from Gallim."

Was this lawful in Israel? Could a father, even if king, give his married daughter to another man, and worse, without the consent of the husband? (In **1 Sam. 18:20** we read that Michal loved David.)

NOTE: Of course, Saul may have considered David an outlaw. Does it matter?

Comment: He had no legal right - it was probably done our of spite for David.  Both knew this and after Saul's death, David demanded his wife return to the great regret of her then "husband."

Comment: @Dottard Interesting. Can you tell me where I can read more about that? Thanks.

Comment: See 2 Sam 3:13-15.

Comment: Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did Saul have a legal right to give David's wife away (1 Sam. 25:44)?

No.

Deuteronomy 24:

> 1
> If a man marries a woman, but she becomes displeasing to him because he finds some indecency in her, he may **write** her a certificate of divorce, hand it to her, and send her away from his house.

David had never issued this certificate of divorce.

Exodus 20:

> 14
> You shall not commit adultery.

Leviticus 20:

> 10
> “’If a man commits adultery with another man’s wife—with the wife of his neighbor—both the adulterer and the adulteress are to be put to death.

Isaiah 50:

> 1a
> This is what the LORD says: “Where is your mother’s certificate of divorce with which I sent her away?

David didn't write the divorce paper. Saul had to right to give his wife away.

King Saul was not above the law, Deuteronomy 17:

> 18
> When he takes the throne of his kingdom, he is to write for himself on a scroll a copy of this law, taken from that of the Levitical priests.

Saul may have considered David an outlaw. Does it matter?

No. Everyone had to follow the Law.

Comment: Excellent answer Tony! Just what I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 2):

[Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.25.43?lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_I_Samuel.25.43.1&lang2=bi) addresses this question thoroughly, but in Hebrew.  I struggle with the translation, but here is a basic summary.

Apparently Saul forced a divorce of Michal from David.  If David considered it legal, he would not have taken Michal back.  That would have been unlawful.

> Then David sent messengers to Ish-bosheth, Saul’s son, saying, “Give me my wife Michal, for whom I paid the bridal price of a hundred foreskins of the Philistines.”
> (2 Sam. 3:14, ESV)

David asking for Michal indicates that David consider the divorce forced by Saul to be illegal and his marriage to Michal still binding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go against the other answers and say yes. Or at least it's not the only time we see a father having his daughter remarry without consulting her husband, which makes me think that legally it was something Saul could have done.

> 15 After a while, at the time of wheat harvest, Samson went to visit his wife with a kid; and he said, “I will go in to my wife in the chamber.” But her father would not allow him to go in. 2 And her father said, “I really thought that you utterly hated her; so I gave her to your companion. Is not her younger sister fairer than she? Pray take her instead.”

[Judges 15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges%2015&version=RSVCE)

Also, Saul was the king. I'm pretty sure that he could change the law if he wanted.

Was he morally correct? No, but I believe that he wasn't breaking the law.